# How to insert a number before each node on a list (C)?

Tags: c

Basically, I'm on a list and I have to insert the number 999 before each node (only when the node is even).

I could do it with the first one.
I also could insert the number after it. 
But I don't know how to insert the number before the node.

I will probably have to modify the function void insertar2 because at the moment, it's inserting the new number after the node (not before as I expect).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define CANTIDAD_NUMEROS 10
#define DESDE 1
#define HASTA 10

typedef struct lista{
    int num;
    struct lista *sig;
 }nodo;


void crear (nodo *pt, int);
void mostrar(nodo *pt);
nodo* insertar1(nodo* );
nodo* eliminar1(nodo* );
void insertar2 (nodo* );
void eliminar2(nodo* );


int main()
{
    int i=0;
    nodo *prin;

    srand(time(NULL));  //Inicio la semilla para generar numeros aleatorios - una sola vez en el main

    prin=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    crear(prin,i);
     //mostrar (prin);
    prin = insertar1(prin);
    insertar2(prin);
     mostrar (prin);



    return 0;
}

void crear (nodo *registro,int cont)
{

    registro->num = rand () % (HASTA-DESDE+1) + DESDE;

    if (cont==CANTIDAD_NUMEROS) //si cambia se convierte en 1
        registro->sig=NULL;
    else
    {

        registro->sig=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        cont++;
        crear (registro->sig,cont);

    }
    return;
}

void mostrar (nodo *registro)
{
    if (registro->sig !=NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d\n",registro->num);
        mostrar (registro->sig);
    }
    return;
}


//modelos a utilizar... modificarlos segun el ejercicio.
nodo* insertar1(nodo *p)
{
    nodo *aux;
    if(p->num%2==0)
    {
        aux=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        aux->num=999;//valor a insertar
        aux->sig=p;
        p=aux;
    }
    return p;
}

void insertar2 (nodo *p)
{nodo *aux;
    while(p->sig!=NULL)
    {
        if(p->num%2==0) //condicion de insercion
        {
            aux=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            aux->num=999;//valor a insertar
            aux->sig=p->sig;
            p->sig=aux;

        }
        p=p->sig;
    }
}
```

Sorry if the Spanish names of the functions/variables are confusing.

Comment: OT: regarding: `{nodo *aux;`   Please, for ease of understanding and readability, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `aux=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));`   1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" )`  and do not try to use the results of that call to `malloc()`  2) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: when ever calling: `... = malloc(sizeof(nodo));`  always set the field: `->sig` to NULL

Answer (score 0):

suggest changing;

```
nodo* insertar1(nodo *p)
{
    nodo *aux;
    if(p->num%2==0)
    {
        aux = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        aux->num = 999;//valor a insertar
        aux->sig = p;
        p=aux;
    }
    return p;
}
```

to insert a new node before the entry pointed to by `p`.

```
nodo* insertar1(nodo *p)
{
    nodo *aux = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    aux->sig  = p;
    aux->num  = p->num+1;

    if(p->num%2==0)
    {
        p->num = 999;
    }

    return aux;
}
```

which still needs error checking on the value returned from `malloc()`